# Do large sets have this specific type of self-similarity?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, integers, pigeonhole-principle, ramsey-theory, erdos-conjecture

> Suppose $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a strictly increasing sequence of
> positive integers such that $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}
>  \frac{1}{a_n}$ diverges, i.e. $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is "large".
>
> Is it true that for every $k\in\mathbb{N},$ there exists a subsequence
> of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of length $k,\ (a_{n_i})_{i=1}^{k},\ $ and
> integers $c\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $d\geq 1$ with $(c,d) \neq (0,1),\ $ such that $(c
>  + d a_{n_i})_{i=1}^{k}$ is also a subsequence of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ ?

It is easy to come up with counter-examples for "small" sets of positive integers i.e. ones where $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{a_n}$ converges, by avoiding the self-similarity when you choose the next number (you can even do this for $k=3$, for example) but I doubt a similar low-complexity (i.e. elementary) construction will work for large sets.

If we assume [Erdős conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_conjecture_on_arithmetic_progressions) to be true, then the proposition is true, because under this assumption, for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$ we can find an A.P. $a, a+b, a+2b, \ldots, a+kb$ of length $k+1$, and then let $a_{n_1} = a,\ a_{n_2} = a+b,\ \ldots, a_{n_k} = a+(k-1)b,\ $ and $\ c= b;\ d=1$. So if the proposition had a counter-example, then this would also be a counter-example to Erdős conjecture, which seems unrealistically simple considering all the advanced attempts to solve Erdős conjecture. Also, Erdős conjecture is an open problem, so we cannot use it in trying to prove the affirmative of the proposition..

Possibly relevant are my previous questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4768489/on-a-weak-polynomial-version-of-erd%C5%91s-conjecture) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4741176/has-this-weak-version-of-erd%C5%91s-conjecture-on-arithmetic-progressions-been-proven).

Comment: Any reason why $(c,d)\neq (1,1)$ is imposed?

Comment: @user10354138 You're right. I edited the question. Does it make more sense now? It's meant to avoid the trivial case...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, such self-similarity must exist. In fact, we can even take $d = 1$.

Let $A$ denote this sequence. The point is that, if the desired self-similarity does not exist for some $k$, then for each positive integer $n$, the equation
$$a - b = n, a, b \in A$$
can have at most $k - 1$ solutions. This is a well-studied situation in the theory of Sidon sets. We can show that

**Lemma**: Write $A_N = |A \cap \{1,2,\cdots, N\}|$. For each $N$, we have $|A_N| \leq \sqrt{4kN}.$

**Proof**: Consider the tuple $B = (a - b: a, b \in A_N)$. For each $a > b$ in $A_N \cap \{1,2,\cdots, N\}$, $a - b$ lies in $\{1,2, \cdots, N\}$. As each possibility can appear at most $k$ times in $B$, we have
$$\binom{|A_N|}{2} = |B| \leq kN$$
and the desired result follows.

Now we can note that
$$\sum_{a \in A} \frac{1}{a} \leq \sum_{t = 1}^\infty \frac{|A_{2^t}|}{2^t}$$
which clearly converges.

Comment: I have not heard of Sidon sets before...

Comment: Well the proof is elementary and not reliant on any prior knowledge of Sidon sets.

Comment: Thanks. The are likely of interest to me, so I am glad you pointed out their existence.

Comment: Nit pick: Shouldn't the last inequality be $\sum_{a \in A} \frac{1}{a} \leq \sum_{t = 0}^\infty \frac{|A_{2^t}|}{2^t}$ ?

Comment: Sorry but now I think about it, the last inequality still isn't clear to me why it holds. Is it basically from Cauchy's Condensation?

Comment: I guess this is a similar idea...The point is that you can bound the sum of $1 / a$ for $a \in [2^{t - 1}, 2^t]$ by $|A_t| / 2^{t - 1}$. This already give you the desired inequality up to a factor of $2$, and you can get that factor with more work.